# How to filter paragraphs by the field name on parent using entityQuery?

Tags: 8, entities

I have a paragraph type `my_paragraph` which is attached to a node type `my_content_type` on multiple fields like `field_a`, `field_b`, `field_c`, `field_d`. I want to load only those attached to some specific fields, let's say `field_a` and `field_c`. I am using `entityQuery`, but open to other suggestions.

The entity/field structure is like:

```
my_content_type: Node
|_ field_a: Paragraph (type: my_paragraph)
|_ field_b: Paragraph (type: my_paragraph)
|_ field_c: Paragraph (type: my_paragraph)
|_ field_d: Paragraph (type: my_paragraph)
```

My code which loads all paragraphs of type:

```php
\Drupal::entityQuery('paragraph')
  ->condition('type', 'my_paragraph')
  // Here I want to filter by the field name on the parent entity
  ->condition('PARENT_FIELD', ['field_a', 'field_c'], 'IN')
  // Some more conditions out of context
  ->condition('out_of_context_field', $out_of_context_value)
  ->execute();
```

Is there any entity query condition I can use here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifically with Paragraphs there are three extra fields directly on Paragraph level, which are accessible with EntityQuery: `parent_id`, `parent_type` (entity type like "node", not bundle name like "page"), `parent_field_name`

You can use those three with EQ like a normal field, e.g.

```
->condition('parent_field_name', ['field_a', 'field_c'], 'IN')
```

Notice that those three fields are only available for Paragraphs, it will not work with any other entity type.

Comment: Great, thanks! Exactly what I was looking for. Where is this documented? I googled about this for an hour and didn't find any documentation.

Comment: I reckon the “documentation” will be reading the `baseFieldDefinitions` method of the paragraph entity type